# How to prevent divs from moving around when resizing?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to design a single page website but whenever I resize the page my contact form moves upward.

I'm trying to have it stay fixed against a background image. How do I make the div stay put?

My Html:

```
            <head>

                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                <meta name="description" content="">
                <meta name="author" content="">

                <title>Title</title>

                <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
                <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 

                <!-- Custom CSS -->
                <link href="css/full-slider.css" rel="stylesheet">
                <link href="css/full-slider.css" rel="stylesheet">
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/demo.css">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/footer-distributed-with-address-and-phones.css">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

                <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cookie" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
                <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.6/angular.js"></script> 
                <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
                <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
                <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
                <!--[if lt IE 9]>
                    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
                    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
                <![endif]-->

            </head>



                <!-- Navigation -->
                <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
                    <div class="container">
                        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            </button>
                            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#About">About</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#Services">What we do</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#Contact">Portfolio</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#Form">Contact</a>
                                </li>

                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.container -->
                </nav>

                <!-- Full Page Image Background Carousel Header -->
                <header id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
                    <!-- Indicators -->
                    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                    </ol>

                    <!-- Wrapper for Slides -->
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="item active">
                            <!-- Set the first background image using inline CSS below. -->
                            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080&text=Slide One');"></div>
                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                                <h2>1</h2>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <!-- Set the second background image using inline CSS below. -->
                            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080&text=Slide Two');"></div>
                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                                <h2>2</h2>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <!-- Set the third background image using inline CSS below. -->
                            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080&text=Slide Three');"></div>
                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                                <h2>3</h2>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Controls -->
                    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
                        <span class="icon-prev"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
                        <span class="icon-next"></span>
                    </a>

                </header>

                        <body>
             <!-- Page Content -->
                <div class="container">

                    <hr class="featurette-divider">

                    <!-- First Featurette -->
                    <div class="featurette" id="About">
                        <img class="featurette-image img-circle img-responsive pull-right" src="http://placehold.it/500x500">
                        <h2 class="featurette-heading">Bla Bla Bla
                            <span class="text-muted">More Bla Bla Bla</span>
                        </h2>
                        <p class="lead">Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo.</p>
                    </div>

                    <hr class="featurette-divider">

                    <!-- Second Featurette -->
                    <div class="featurette" id="Services">
                        <img class="featurette-image img-circle img-responsive pull-left" src="http://placehold.it/500x500">
                        <h2 class="featurette-heading">More text goes here
                            <span class="text-muted">There will be additional things written.</span>
                        </h2>
                        <p class="lead">Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo.</p>
                    </div>

                    <hr class="featurette-divider">

                    <!-- Third Featurette -->
                    <div class="featurette" id="Contact">
                        <img class="featurette-image img-circle img-responsive pull-right" src="http://placehold.it/500x500">
                        <h2 class="featurette-heading">Final Part
                            <span class="text-muted">Will Seal the Deal.</span>
                        </h2>
                        <p class="lead">Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo.</p>
                    </div>

                    <hr class="featurette-divider">

                    <!-- Contact -->



                <p class="intro">
            This is where the contact form will go</p> 
            </div>
            <br>



            <form ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="validateCtrl"
            name="myForm" novalidate>

            <div id="wrap">
                <img class="image" src="http://thekitemap.com/images/feedback-img.jpg">
              <div id="form-div">
                <form class="form" id="form1">
            <p><br>
            <input type="text" name="user" ng-model="user" ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="9" required placeholder="Name">
            <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.user.$dirty && myForm.user.$invalid">
            <span ng-show="myForm.user.$error.required">A name is required.</span>
            <span ng-show="myForm.user.$error.minlength">Name is too short.</span>
            <span ng-show="myForm.user.$error.maxlength"> Name is too long.</span>
            </span>
            </p>


            <p><br>
            <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="email" required placeholder="Email">
            <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.email.$dirty && myForm.email.$invalid">
            <span ng-show="myForm.email.$error.required">Email address is required.</span>
            <span ng-show="myForm.email.$error.email">Invalid email address.</span>
            </span>
            </p>

            <p class="inputfield"><label for="message"><br></label></p> 
                <textarea name="message" id="message" tabindex="2" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>

            <p>
            <div class="submit">
                <input type="submit" value="SEND" id="button-blue"
            ng-disabled="myForm.user.$dirty && myForm.user.$invalid ||
            myForm.email.$dirty && myForm.email.$invalid"/>
                    <div class="ease"></div>
                </div>
            </p>

            </form>
            </div>

            <script>
            var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
            app.controller('validateCtrl', function($scope) {
                $scope.user = '';
                $scope.email = '';
            });
            </script>

            </div>
            </body>

            <br>

            <!--Footer-->
            <footer class="footer-distributed">

                        <div class="footer-left">

                            <h3>Company<span>logo</span></h3>

                            <p class="footer-links">
                                <a href="#">Home</a>
                                ·
                                <a href="#">About</a>
                                ·
                                <a href="#">What we do</a>
                                ·
                                <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
                                ·
                                <a href="#">Contact</a>

                            </p>

                            <p class="footer-company-name">Firm &copy; 2015</p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="footer-center">

                            <div>
                                <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
                                <p><span>1 Main Street</span> City, Country</p>
                            </div>

                            <div>
                                <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                                <p>+5 555 123456</p>
                            </div>

                            <div>
                                <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                                <p><a href="mailto:support@company.com">email@company.com</a></p>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="footer-right">

                            <p class="footer-company-about">
                                <span>About Us</span>
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectateur adispicing elit. Fusce euismod convallis velit, eu auctor lacus vehicula sit amet.
                            </p>

                            <div class="footer-icons">

                                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </footer>

                <!-- /.container -->

                <!-- jQuery -->
                <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

                <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
                <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



                <!-- /.container -->

                <!-- jQuery -->
                <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

                <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
                <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

                <!-- Script to Activate the Carousel -->
                <script>
                $('.carousel').carousel({
                    interval: 5000 //changes the speed
                })
                </script>

             </html>
```

MY CSS: 
@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700');

```
            *{
                padding:0;
                margin:0;
            }

            html{
                background-color: #eaf0f2;
            }

            body{
                font:14px/1.5 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                min-width: 750px;
            }

            header{
                text-align: center;
                padding-top: 100px;
                margin-bottom:200px;
            }

            header h1{
                font: normal 32px/1.5 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
                color: #3F71AE;
                padding-bottom: 16px;
            }

            header h2{
                color: #F05283;
            }

            header h2 a{
                color:inherit;
                text-decoration: none;
                display: inline-block;
                border: 1px solid #F05283;
                padding: 10px 15px;
                border-radius: 3px;
                font: bold 14px/1 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
                text-transform: uppercase;
            }

            header h2 a:hover{
                background-color:#F05283;
                transition: 0.2s;
                color:#fff;
            }

            header ul {
                max-width: 600px;
                margin: 60px auto 0;
            }

            header ul a{
                text-decoration: none;
                color: #FFF;
                text-align: left;
                background-color: #B9C1CA;
                padding: 10px 16px;
                border-radius: 2px;
                opacity: 0.8;
                font-size: 16px;
                display: inline-block;
                margin: 4px;
                line-height: 1;
                outline: none;

                transition: 0.2s ease;
            }

            header ul li a.active{
                background-color: #66B650;
                pointer-events: none;
            }

            header ul li a:hover {
                opacity: 1;
            }

            header ul{
                list-style: none;
                padding: 0;
            }

            header ul li{
                display: inline-block;
            }
            .container{
                margin-left:auto;
                margin-right:auto;
                width:960px;
            }

            .validation-message {
                color: #f00;
            }

            #feedback-page{
                text-align:center;
            }
            .image {
                width:100%;
                height:100%;

            }
            #wrap {
                width: 100%;
                float:left;
                padding-top:0px;

            }

            #form-div {
                background-color:rgba(72,72,72,0.4);
                padding-left:35px;
                padding-right:35px;
                padding-top:35px;
                padding-bottom:50px;
                width: 450px;
                float: left;
                left: 50%;
                position: absolute;
                margin-top:-730px;
                margin-left: -260px;
              -moz-border-radius: 7px;
              -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
            }

            .feedback-input {
                color:#3c3c3c;
                font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
                font-weight:500;
                font-size: 18px;
                border-radius: 0;
                line-height: 22px;
                background-color: #fbfbfb;
                padding: 13px 13px 13px 54px;
                margin-bottom: 10px;
                width:100%;
                -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
                -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
                -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
                box-sizing: border-box;
              border: 3px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
            }

            .feedback-input:focus{
                background: #fff;
                box-shadow: 0;
                border: 3px solid #3498db;
                color: #3498db;
                outline: none;
              padding: 13px 13px 13px 54px;
            }

            .focused{
                color:#30aed6;
                border:#30aed6 solid 3px;
            }
            input[type="text"] {
                display: inline;
                width: 100%;
                height: 30px;
                font-size: 16px;
                background-color:white;
                font-family: 'Lato';

            }
            input[type="email"] {
                display: inline;
                width: 100%;
                height: 30px;
                font-size: 16px;
                background-color: white;
                font-family: 'Lato';

            }
            /* Icons ---------------------------------- */

            textarea {
                width: 100%;
                height: 150px;
                line-height: 150%;
                resize:vertical;
            }

            input:hover, textarea:hover,
            input:focus, textarea:focus {
                background-color:white;
            }

            #button-blue{
                font-family: 'Montserrat', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                float:left;
                width: 100%;
                border: #fbfbfb solid 4px;
                cursor:pointer;
                background-color: #3498db;
                color:white;
                font-size:24px;
                padding-top:22px;
                padding-bottom:22px;
                -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
                -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
                transition: all 0.3s;
                margin-top:-4px;
                font-weight:700;
            }

            #button-blue:hover{
                background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
                color: #0493bd;
            }

            .submit:hover {
                color: #3498db;
            }

            .ease {
                width: 0px;
                height: 74px;
                background-color: #fbfbfb;
                -webkit-transition: .3s ease;
                -moz-transition: .3s ease;
                -o-transition: .3s ease;
                -ms-transition: .3s ease;
                transition: .3s ease;
            }

            .submit:hover .ease{
              width: 100%;
              background-color:white;
            }

            @media only screen and (max-width: 580px) {
                #form-div{
                    left: 3%;
                    margin-right: 3%;
                    width: 88%;
                    margin-left: 0;
                    padding-left: 3%;
                    padding-right: 3%;
                }
            }


            footer{
                position: fixed;
                bottom: 0px;
            }

            @media (max-height:800px){
                footer { position: static; }
                header { padding-top:40px; }
            }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5rc1c7dL/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5rc1c7dL/1/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add code snippet and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!

Comment: @Michael_B Great! Thanks!